# Interface than allow a function to return an IEnumerable<TD> or IQueryable<TD> based on the query

Tags: c#, linq, interface

My objective here, is to apply the pattern strategy. To do so, I "explode" my class where I make all my database requests  and use those call

```
new DBRequest1().Exec();
new DbRequest2(id).Exec();
```

the DBRequest classes look to some thing like this :

```
interface IDBRequest
{
    TR Exec<TR, TD>() where TR : IEnumerable<TD>, IQueryable<TD>;
}

class DBRequest1 : IDBRequestDB
{
  public DBRequest1(){ } //constructor
  public TR Exec<TR, TD>() where TR : IEnumerable<TD>, IQueryable<TD> {
    return Enumerable.Empty<Models.Table1Element>();
  }
}

class DBRequest2 : IDBRequestDB
{
  private int Id{get;set;}
  public DBRequest2(in id){ Id = id; } //constructor
  public TR Exec<TR, TD>() where TR : IEnumerable<TD>, IQueryable<TD> {
    return MY_DATABASE.Table2.Where(r=>r.id == Id);
  }
}
```

obviously this not working. I could use

```
IEnumerable<object> Exec();
```

and cast all elements to object, but it come quite messy to use...
How should I set the method signature/body to allow Exec() to return an IEnumerable, IQueryable where TD is only dicted by the linQ result?
is it only possible?

Comment: Well, an `IQueryable<TD>` IS an `IEnumerable<TD>`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have only one genetic parameter - TD. It is not possible to specify"IQueryable or IEnumerable" return type for the method, so you should pick one interface to use:

```
interface IDBRequest<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Exec();
}

class DBRequest1 : IDBRequest<Models.Table1Element>
{
    public IEnumerable<Models.Table1Element> Exec()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<Models.Table1Element>();
    }
}

class DBRequest2 : IDBRequest<Models.Table1Element>
{
    public IEnumerable<Models.Table1Element> Exec()
    {
        // fetch from DB
        return MY_DATABASE.Table2.Where(r=>r.id == Id);
    }
}
```

or, for IQueryable:

```
interface IDBRequest<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> Exec();
}

class DBRequest1 : IDBRequest<Models.Table1Element>
{
    public IQueryable<Models.Table1Element> Exec()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<Models.Table1Element>().AsQueryable();
    }
}

class DBRequest2 : IDBRequest<Models.Table1Element>
{
    public IQueryable<Models.Table1Element> Exec()
    {
        // fetch from DB
        return MY_DATABASE.Table2.Where(r=>r.id == Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya, I feared than it will be this way. Anyway, thanx you!